# How to return the absolute url

Tags: php

I've been trying to insert an image inside a php generated image (using imagecreatefromX() where x = gif, jpeg, or png) using a GET perimeter as the source url. I try to have it check what MIME type it is, by doing this:

```
$pic = $_GET['pic'];

switch(returnMIMEType($pic)) {

    case "image/gif":
        $profileImage = @imagecreatefromgif($pic) or die('Unable to load gif image.');
        break;

    case "image/jpg":
        $profileImage = @imagecreatefromjpeg($pic) or die('Unable to load jpeg image.');
        break;

    case "image/png":
        $profileImage = @imagecreatefrompng($pic) or die('Unable to load png image.');
        break;

    default:
        $pic = 'http://www.example.com/image.gif';
        $profileImage = @imagecreatefromgif($pic) or die('Unable to load gif image.');
        break;   
}

$profileImageWidth = imagesx($profileImage);
$profileImageHeight = imagesy($profileImage);

imagecopyresized($image, $profileImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25, 25, $profileImageWidth, $profileImageHeight);
```

returnMIMEType() is just a simple function I came up with to return the MIME type.

When a url is given in this format: "http://graph.facebook.com/123456789/picture", it should return with a jpg image of the users profile picture on Facebook, but I'm assuming, and which is what I'm having issues with, is PHP is looking at that exact URL and not the url "http://graph.facebook.com/123456789/picture" redirects too. How would I have it so it understands to wait until the redirect?

Thank you for your consideration in this matter!

**Here is the error it gives:**

```
Warning: mime_content_type() [function.mime-content-type]: File or path not found
'http://graph.facebook.com/123456789/picture'
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you try this? As a first step, remove the `@` to get meaningful error messages. A redirect is a possibility but it could have other reasons too

Comment: Updated post with the error it gives. Removing the '@' did not change the output however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redirect should not be an issue. Chances are, you have the ini setting [allow_url_fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) set to false, so you are not allowed to open urls with file functions, and the error is being suppressed because you are using `@`. Try double checking that you have enabled `allow_url_fopen`, and if that doesn't work, try removing the `@` for a more meaningful error message.

I tried using the http://graph.facebook.com/123456789/picture url and `imagecreatefromgif(), and it worked just fine for me.

**EDIT:** fileinfo functions do not like URLs. Try the following to the the mime type:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime_type = finfo_buffer($finfo, file_get_contents($url));
```

Comment: I tried to use ini_set() but with no avail. I don't happen to be using fopen, just imagecopyresized();. Should I be using fopen before?

Comment: Sorry, wrote that before you edited in your error message. `allow_url_fopen` applies to most all functions that open files, but that doesn't seem to be the issue here. Try the updated code I posted.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! Although webbiedave mentions saving bandwidth, you are the one that fixed the issue first. Kudos to you both. :)